# Async Task and Progress Bar

Tags: android, asynchronous, progress

I have two async tasks. Let's say A and B. A is first executed and on the post executed B is called. Now I need to show the progress bar after Task B ends. Like a percentage from 0 starting A and 100 endings of B. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

in your `onPreExecute` and `onProgressUpdate` from asynctask A :

```
  @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //show progress bar

    }
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     ProgressBar.setProgress(progress[0]/2)//we will take only 50% of the progress
    }
```

in your `onPostExecute` and `onProgressUpdate` in your asynctask B

```
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    ProgressBar.setProgress(progress[0]/2)//we will take the other  50% of the progress
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
    //hide progress here
    }
```

please make sure to make your progress bar local so you can access it from both asynctask

Answer (score 0):

Within `AsyncTasks` you can update the UI on `onProgressUpdate` or `onPostExecute` callbacks. These two callbacks run in the **main (UI)** thread, whereas `doInBackground` runs in a **worker** thread.

In order to make the the "B" progress bar showing after the completion of `AsynctaskA` I would start the `AsyncTaskB` in the `onPostExecute` callback of `AsyncTaskA`, then update the progress bar B in its `onProgressUpdate` callback

```java
public ProgressBar progressBarA = ProgressBar(this); // init with a progress bar coming from the UI here
public ProgressBar progressBarB = ProgressBar(this); // init with a progress bar coming from the UI here

    private class AsyncTaskA extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean> {
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // do something in the background here
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                publishProgress(i);
            }
            return true;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            progressBarA.setProgress(progress[0]);
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            AsyncTaskB taskB = new AsyncTaskB();
            taskB.execute();
        }
    }

    private class AsyncTaskB extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressBarB.setProgress(0);
        }

        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // do something in the background here
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                publishProgress(i);
            }
            return true;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            progressBarB.setProgress(progress[0]);
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // Toast work complete!
        }
    }
```